# hook_field_schema() does not work

Tags: 7, entities

I'm creating a module to introduce a new field type. I downloaded the example module by drupal and i start programming.
But when I install the module the .install don't add colums to the dbtable related to new field.

```
 function field_instagram_field_schema($field) {

   watchdog('start field_instagram_field_schema()', 'We are in!');

   switch ($field['type']) {
    case 'instagram_gallery':
      $columns = array(
        'stream_type' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '25',
          'not null' => FALSE
        ),
        'input_tag' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '25',
          'not null' => FALSE
        ),
         'thumb_dimetion' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '25',
          'not null' => FALSE
        ),
        'thumb_number' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => '25',
          'not null' => FALSE
        )
      );
      break;
  }

  return array('columns' => $columns);
}
```

**UPDATED**
When i install the module and create a field of this new type this function is not runned..

Comment: Have you definitely un-installed and re-installed the module rather than just disabling it and re-enabling it (they're different things)?

Comment: Yes, I do multiple times T_T

Comment: Sorry, I had to ask :) Just to rule out the more obvious things - is the module called `field_instagram`? Where is this code, the .install file or .module file? Have you tried putting some debug code in the function (a `watchdog()` call for example) to see if the function is definitely being executed when the module is installed?

Comment: I tryed right now to add a watchdog() call at the 1st line of this function and, whene i install the module (and create a field..), there isn't message in the log.. so the function is not runned..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, but nothing will happen when you install the module itself. It will only be invoked when you create a new field of type `instagram_gallery`.

But that is not all. The only module that will get's it `hook_field_schema` invoked, is the module that actually defined the field. This is done with `hook_field_info`, so you need to have the following code in your `field_instagram.module` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_info().
 */
function field_instagram_field_info() {
  return array(
    'instagram_gallery' => array(
      ...
    ),
  );
}
```

Since you are defining your own field, you also need to use

- `hook_field_is_empty`
- `hook_field_formatter_info`
- `hook_field_formatter_view`
- `hook_field_widget_info` (unless you can use an existing widget)

**Update**
It's hard to say way you have troubles. What the field module does is this:

```
module_load_install($field['module']);
$schema = (array) module_invoke($field['module'], 'field_schema', $field);
```

You can try to load the created field manually and run the hook to see if it works. You need to load the `.install` file like shown above. My guess is that you have something misnamed somewhere, but it's hard to say where exactly. The above could should with your info look like this:

```
$field = field_info_field('field_name_here');
module_load_install('field_instagram');
$schema = (array) module_invoke('field_instagram', 'field_schema', $field);
```

If the above works, you can try to debug the actual field creation, the code is from field.crud.inc line 134.

Comment: I never realised the hook only gets invoked when a field is created but it makes a whole lot of sense. Really useful thanks :)

Comment: I create this field type in my field_instagram.module and i have all this function in my module.. 
I check the database table after a field creation obviously..

Comment: @Shyghar Added more info - hope it helps.

Comment: After some tests I tryed to rewrite the module and now it works -__-"

I think it was a naming problem hard to find.. tnks a lot for the help ^^